# Thousands of frames per second?

Tags: camera

Are there any (consumer) cameras, capable of shooting ~1000 frames per second?

Googling for high speed cameras I found that `GoPro` is able to take 120 frames per second and some of `Photron` or `Rapatronic` cameras, capable to shot millions of frames per second and costing millions of dollars.

Are the intermediate cameras?

Comment: A google search using those search terms gives me a wide range of cameras at speeds including 700, 1000, 10000 fps.

Comment: You would need many more parameters than that. What about the resolution, duration, etc. Some camera are capable of 1,000 fps but only for like 1 or 2 seconds and only HD. Do you need 4K, 8K, minutes in duration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Casio EX-F1 can shoot upto 1200fps, but the resolution reduces as the frame rate gets higher.  They go on eBay for about £600.

http://www.casio.com/products/archive/Digital_Cameras/High-Speed/EX-F1/

Or the Casio Exilim FH20, for about £300 on Amazon, was used to make this:

More info on how it was made here:

http://straylight.co.uk/?p=120